# How to handle action dispatching for a nested React Redux component

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm doing something like this for my UI component in a React Redux app:

```
// Outer.js
import Inner from './path'

export const Outer = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <Inner />
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
// Inner.js
const param = ''
export const Inner = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField 
                input={param}
                onChange = {(param) => {
                    Function(param)
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I also set up a Container component for Outer.js:

```
// OuterContainer.js
import Outer from './path'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    paramToBeUpdated: ???
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    Function: (param) => dispatch(Function(param))
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Outer)
```

My action created for this step:

```
action/index.js
export const Function = (param) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FUNCTION', param })
}
```

And my reducer included the following function:

```
// reducer.js
export default reducer = (state="", action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'FUNCTION':
            return {
                ...state,
                param: action.param
            }
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update the variable `paramToBeUpdated`'s value from the Inner UI component. But it didn't work.

Can `Inner` and `Outer` components share a container component connected with `Outer`?

How should I do it without making too much changes to my current setup? Is it possible to avoid creating a new Inner container, which will basically be a copy of the Outer container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't connect Inner with the state value and or the action then you must have done something wrong, here is a working example:

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { produce } = immer;

const initialState = {
  value: '',
};
//action types
const CHANGE = 'CHANGE';
//action creators

const change = (value) => ({
  type: CHANGE,
  payload: value,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === CHANGE) {
    return produce(state, (draft) => {
      draft.value = payload;
    });
  }
  return state;
};
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
//components
const Inner = connect((state) => state.value, {
  Function: change,
})(({ Function, value }) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => Function(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
});

const Outer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Inner />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Outer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immer@7.0.5/dist/immer.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It turned out I did not use ```e.target.value``` when passing param, also forgot to return ```Function```. I'm having a little trouble binding the input value as the payload at the moment since I'm actually using an Autocomplete text field from material-ui lab instead of a plain input field. Do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: By the way, I don't understand what's inside your applyMiddleware(). Mind explain what's happening there?

Comment: @Young It's a [middleware function](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#the-final-approach) `store=>next=>action` that does nothing. I use the code sometimes to demo thunk so I can replace it with `store=>next=>action=>typeof action === 'function'?action(store.dispatch,store.getState):next(action)`

Answer (score 0):

Only `Outer` is connected to the redux store.
If you want to dispatch an action from `Inner` you may do:

1. Connect Inner to the redux store

```js
// Inner.js
const Inner = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField 
                input={param}
                onChange = {(param) => {
                    props.Function(param)
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Inner)
```

no need to create any `InnerContainer`

2. Pass dispatch function  from `Outer` (+  no need for Container)

```js
// Outer.js
import Inner from './path'

export const Outer = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <Inner Function={props.Function} />
            ...
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    paramToBeUpdated: ???
}

const mapStateToProps = (dispatch) => {
    Function: (param) => dispatch(Function(param))
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Outer)
```

```js
// Inner.js
const Inner = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField 
                input={param}
                onChange = {(param) => {
                    props.Function(param)
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried in my app and added a ```mapDispatchToProps``` method to Inner.js and passed the function through ```props```. But I'm still getting the same error that Function (or props.Function) does not exist in Inner. I don't know how to make the function visible in Inner.